# How to add a column from another data frame to my own that are united by sample_id?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, filtering

I'm new to R and was wondering how I'd go about adding a column from datasetA to datasetB that are united by a sampleID.

In particular datasetA has the name of individuals while datasetB has the age of those same individuals as specified by a sampleID. (i.e "We know someone named Cat through sampleID 001 in datasetA but their age is in datasetB).

How would I create a new column in datasetA named "age" which would have the same information as the datasetB age. A sample can be seen below of the 2 datasets

DatasetA

| sampleID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Cat |
| 002 | Dog |
| 003 | Pig |
| 004 | Cow |
| 005 | Duck |

DatasetB

| sampleID | Age |
| --- | --- |
| 005 | 2 |
| 003 | 5 |
| 002 | 4 |
| 004 | 2 |
| 001 | 1 |

Essentially I want to add the age column from datasetB to datasetA (keep in mind that the sampleIDs are scrambled in DatasetB)

I've tried a few solutions myself but nothing has worked

```
new_metadata <- merge(A, B, by = "sampleID")
```

This just duplicated all the samples. Given the real dataset has over 300 columns manually adding the ages is too cumbersome especially given that the sampleIDs are scrambled all over the place.

I tried to use the mutate function of dpylr

```
 mutate(age = if_else(datasetB$age >= 0, datasetB$age, "no_age"))
```

But that didn't work. Is there a function that I'm missing that can easily accomplish this?

I just need the ages to be added for each sampleID if they match

Let me know if this is even possible because it seems like a simple action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you used data.table to store the samples.

```
DatasetA <- data.table(sampleID=c("001","002","003","004","005"),Name=c("Cat","Dog","Pig","Cow","Duck"))
DatasetB <- data.table(sampleID=c("005","003","002","004","001"),Age=c(2,5,4,2,1))
new_metadata <- merge(DatasetA, DatasetB, by = "sampleID")
new_metadata
   sampleID Name Age
1:      001  Cat   1
2:      002  Dog   4
3:      003  Pig   5
4:      004  Cow   2
5:      005 Duck   2
```

Look at str(DatasetA) & str(DatasetA) to see how are you storing the data. Probably a problem with sampleID column (maybe extra spaces or something along the line) that prevent the match to happen.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Just needed to be careful with the sample ID